# How to position images responsively?

Tags: html, css, position

Hello I am having trouble positioning an image over a list item and making it responsive. At full width it works, its positioned correctly, but when I shrink the browser it starts to get out of alignment. You can see what I'm talking about in the pics below.

Full Width: (browser at 1920 px wide)

[image]

After browser has been shrunk: (browser at 1400 px wide)

[image]

HTML: (bare minimum html required for this question)

```
<section class="contact">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="/images/footer_box.svg" >
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="/images/footer_box.svg" >
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="/images/footer_box.svg" >
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS: (bare minimum css required for this question)

```
.contact ul li  {
    position: relative;
}

.contact ul li img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 214px;
    top: -110px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center it.

```
.contact ul li img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```